# PHP using variable for require location

Tags: php, require

I believe my problem should be simple, but no matter how much looking I do I cant find a solution :(

I am trying the following....

File structure.....

-Folder 1

-Folder 2

-loader.php

-admin.php

loader.php contents...

```
<?php // $_GET['l'] == admin.php
 $location = $_GET['l'];
 require $location;
?>
```

admin.php contents .....

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

But this doesnt work. Anything I search only brings results regarding passing the variable to the loaded file. I'm wanting to use the variable to define the location of the file to require.

Surely this is possible somehow!

```
<?php // $_GET['l'] == admin.php
 $location = $_GET['l'];
 require $location;


 $location = $_GET['l'];
 require '$location';
?>
```

i have also tried require|include|require_once|include_once

Comment: Are you sure that required file exists? Have you checked paths?

Comment: path definitely exists and both files are housed in the same folder

Comment: Check the relative path of *admin.php* page with respect to the page where you're doing `$location = $_GET['l']; require $location;`.

Comment: Your code <?php // $_GET['l'] == admin.php
 $location = $_GET['l'];
 require $location;
?> is correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: no errors just no included code :(

Comment: Just to be sure, your URL  ends with ?l=admin.php, yes?

Comment: @BarryThomas yes, $location does contain my get data

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file `admin.php`?

Comment: @RobertWade he has :)

Comment: @BarryThomas. sorry! missed that piece.

Comment: Can you echo your $_GET['l'] in the loader.php file?

Comment: @BarryThomas yes I can "thats what the commented line was supposed to explain :S"

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. I'm not sure so, I have tested this on localhost, and it worked for me.

Comment: In the contents you provided above... is that the only code in those two files?  Or did you just post the 'relevant' parts?

Comment: I just posted relevant parts

Comment: If you just set $location = 'admin.php' does it work then?

Comment: @BarryThomas Bit ashamed that I didnt think to try this :/ you were right it does work! it turns out it wasn't working due to another included file within loader.php having a clashing variable name!! Robert Wade I missed a relevant part haha

Comment: Thanks for all your help!!